# How do I find the region borders in an image using python?

Tags: python, image, numpy, boundary

So I have two numpy arrays- the first is a 3D RGB image. The second is a 2D grid representing the regions in the image (my images generally have around 7 to 20 regions) where each region is represented by an integer.

The the 2D grid looks something like this:

```
[
[0,0,0,1],

[0,0,1,1],

[2,2,2,2]
]
```

Now what I want to do is find an algorithm that tells me exactly where the region borders are so I would expect the algorithm to return the indexes where the border is between regions 0 and 1, 1 and 2, 2 and 1, etc.

So in this case I would get:

Border between 0 and 1: `[0,2] [1,1]`

Border between 0 and 2: `[1,0] [1,1]`

Border between 1 and 2: `[1,2] [1,3]`

Comment: Use this: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

Talking about the algorithm you can use to detect boundaries between regions pro grammatically
You can use any of the edge detector kernels and apply them on your 2d grid to detect differences horizontally or vertically if the outcome is zero then both pixels belong to the same region if the answer is non-zero then you have just found a boundary here.
One of the edge detectors is sobel 
a sobel kernel looks like 

`[-1 0 1]
[-1 0 1]
[-1 0 1]`

and

`[-1 -1 -1 ]
[ 0  0  0 ]
[ 1  1  1 ]`

here is an example of sobel application in python's opencv

```
https://li8bot.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/opencvpythonpart3-image-gradients/
```

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm is written to use with list within lists, but I am sure it can be easily tweak to work with numpy. I have not used numpy yet, thus I could not give You exact answer.

```
def main():
    grid = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2, 2]]

    borders = []


    '''
    It has the following format.
    ['Borders beetwen 0 and 1', [[0, 2], [0, 3]]]
    [0, 2] is coordinate of 0 and [0, 3] is coordinate of 1.
    '''
    for x in range(0, len(grid)-1):

        for y in range(0, len(grid[x])-1):

            if grid[x][y] != grid[x][y+1]:
                header = ['Borders beetwen %s and %s' %(str(grid[x][y]), str(grid[x][y+1]))]
                coords = [[x, y], [x, y+1]]
                header.append(coords)
                borders.append(header)

            else:
                pass

        if grid[x][y] != grid[x+1][y]:
            header = ['Borders beetwen %s and %s' %(str(grid[x][y]), str(grid[x+1][y]))]
            coords = [[x, y], [x+1, y]]
            header.append(coords)
            borders.append(header)

        else:
            pass

    for element in borders:
        print(element)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```